# git show repositories in gitweb only to some users

Tags: git, gitweb

I'm trying to implement a git server with only one developer at first, so the only one with total access. I have no problem to do this already. This user is doing his work with ssh access.

And I would like to share read-only access to the projects with some GUI of some kind (gitweb, gitlist, gitalist...) running on apache that could show the repos I choose to specific users and maybe some totally public. Something like:

- Repo x - Read access for user1 and user3
- Repo y - Read access for user1 and user2
- Repo z - Read access for all users.

I'm not able to find out which is the proper solution to do something like this.

I can find documentation on how to do authentication to show the repos only to authenticated users but not a fine grained control on the repositories to show to each authenticated user only some repos with one of the GUIs running on apache.

I have tried gitweb with dav using the webmin git module but all repositories are shown in gitweb no matter the user I authenticate with have only access to some repositories and not all.

The webserver is running suexec with user git and has total read access to the repos.

How something like this should be implemented? Maybe some hook?

Besides I'm only interested really in the option that allows the users to download the packaged tar.gz of the project. It is not planned to allow the users to collaborate with the project. Maybe the solution is other than this. A trac system if that is better solution could be interesting too, to be able to receive feedback about the projects.

Answer (score 3):

The proper solution is to add an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html) like [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

My [httpd.conf](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl) file, for instance, declares a:

- [gitweb](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49) which will call gitolite, in order to display only the right repository
  (because I have include a [`gitweb.conf.pl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl) file from the native [gitweb file `gitweb_config.perl`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl) )
- an [https access](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95) which will call first gitolite in order to allow or not push/pull/clone commands.

For instance:

```
ScriptAlias /hgit/ @H@/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "@H@/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
```